# Android Chrome and GWT ScrollPanel

Tags: android, google-chrome, gwt

Hy guys!

I'm developing in Vaadin 7.1.1. and want to create a scrollable gwt widget. I made it and it works perfect on desktop Chrome, but in Android ICS I can't scroll it. I've already tried to modify CSS to use these:

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch !important;
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0px);
```

After a few search I've found this issue on Google Forum:

[Scrolling issue](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/4FvwbfBhUjU)

Has anyone met with this problem so far?

Comment: Same problem here, can't find any solution so far.